# Knockout jQuery UI Widget Binding in Templates

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

When using [jquery-ui custom bindings](https://raw.github.com/gist/889400/knockout-jquery-ui-widget.js) to add a datepicker to a text field it only updates my model when I don't use templates.

[Simple JSFiddle demostration of problem](http://jsfiddle.net/tsmarsh/U5qRF/9/)

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/html" id="datepicker-template">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        <input type="text" data-bind="jqueryui: {widget:'datepicker'}, value: $data">
</script>

<h2>Witout templates</h2>
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: from"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="jqueryui: {widget:'datepicker'}, value: from">
    <span data-bind="text: to"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="jqueryui: {widget:'datepicker'}, value: to">
</div>
<h2>With template<h2>
<div data-bind="template: {name:'datepicker-template', foreach: dates}"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
    var ViewModel = function(){
        this.from = ko.observable("from");
        this.to = ko.observable("to");
        this.dates = ko.observableArray([this.from, this.to]);
    };

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();               
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});​
```

Feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Please add your relevant code here, no external links to the actual problem pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is reproducible in a simple example without the jQueryUI bindings. The problem has to do with the `$data` keyword inside of knockout templates.

Apparently `$data` cannot be used for a two-way binding inside of a template. See [this Google Groups thread for some commentary](https://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/929e74437600fb6c/8bc4a3f579383f97?pli=1):

> If you have items: ["one", "two", "three"] or even
>   [ko.observable("one"),  ko.observable("two"), ko.observable("three")]
>   within a foreach $data will  be the raw value and **KO has no way at
>   that point to know how to write back  to it.  You need to use objects
>   with properties**, in the case that you need  to read/write access to
>   the value.

So one way to get around this limitation is to create a simple ViewModel for your date objects:

```
var DateViewModel = function (initialValue) {
    this.value = ko.observable(initialValue);
};
```

And then in your main ViewModel you could write:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.dates = ko.observableArray([
        new DateViewModel("from"),
        new DateViewModel("to")
    ]);
};
```

And your template would end up being something like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="datepicker-template">
    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: value">
</script>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RjEnh/